# Trying to convert output string to UTF-8 when writing to .txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, output

I am attempting to submit lines from a .txt file to the google translate api, and then output those results to a separate .txt file. Everything works except that when I read my output file, it is in unicode, so I end up with characters like /xeda and things like that. I am trying to convert the results to utf-8 before writing to the file, but my attempts have seemed to have no effect. I get no errors, but I also still get the garbage characters. This is what my (relevant) code looks like:

```
read_array = []
write_array = []
write_file = 'write_file.txt'
read_file = open('metaphors1.txt','r')
s = codecs.open('write_file.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')

for line in read_file:
    #Reads sentences from the input file, converts them to a string with
    #all lowercase letters (to prevent garbage values then puts the strings
    #in an array
    readstring = str(line)
    readstring = readstring.lower()
    read_array.append(readstring)

for item in read_array:
    #removes new line symbols to prevent translation errors then submits
    #sentences in the array to the translator, then writes the sentences
    #to a new array
    readitem = str(item)
    readitem.rstrip('\n')
    results1 = translator.translate(readitem)
    resultstring = str(results1)
    write_array.append(resultstring)

for item in write_array:
    #writes the results to an output file
    writeitem = str(item)
    writeitem = writeitem.encode('utf-8')
    s.write("%s\n" % writeitem)

s.close()
```

I am sure whatever I am doing wrong is simple and obvious, but I am stumped on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode, you can even tell it to ignore errors if you don't care about them.

line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm missing something. I added that line and it did nothing. So I added to the beginning:

read = codecs.open('metaphors1.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') and now I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/googletranslator2.py", line 313, in <module>
    line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: what do you want to have happen to the characters that are out of bounds?

Comment: Well, ideally I was looking for a way to make them 'in bounds', but otherwise ignoring them would be fine, which is what I thought the 'ignore' parameter did.

Comment: And I just noticed I didn't add 'ignore' to my encoding line. It still gives me errors however.

Comment: mm, reading this doesn't sound promising unless you happen to have python 3 lying around...

https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: Well, I've been thinking it may be best to just convert to python 3, so I think I'll have to try that at this point. Thanks for your help though!